# Why is determinant called volume of the fundamental parallelepiped in geometry of numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, determinant

Let $v_1, ..., v_n$ be $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
Then they form a lattice $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and the volume of the fundamental domain is $|\det A|$, where $A$ is the matrix obtained by putting $v_i$'s into columns. Could someone explain me why we call this determinant a "volume"?

Comment: It *is* the volume (or area in D2) in the usual sense this word is used. I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you form the parallelepiped by $\{\sum_i c_i v_i \, | \, 0 \leq c_i \leq 1\}$ then the geometric volume of this object in $n$ dimensions is precisely $\det V$ where $V$ is the matrix with column vectors given by the $v_i$. If you'd like an intuitive understanding, note that it works for a cube and it also works for a "sheared" cube where you shift one dimension to the right or left in some axis-perpendicular direction. Also if $\det V = 0$ then the vectors are linearly dependent so the "parallepiped" lies in a lower dimensional hyperplane so the volume in dimension $n$ is $0$.

Comment: When you say "geometric volume" can I take it as the Lebesuge measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is the measure in the traditional sense.

Comment: It's a signed volume. Determinants can be negative. So the order of the vectors matters.

Comment: If you swap two vectors in the matrix then the determinant negates.

Comment: I guess the Lebsegue measure of it agrees with the absolute value of the determinant ?